# How should I interpret this function notation?

Tags: functions, notation, fractional-calculus

I'm trying to implement an FDGD Algorithm from a paper and I'm a little stuck how to interpret a piece of function notation. See page 7, equations 2 and 3 in [this document](http://www.csie.kuas.edu.tw/~cclin321/papers/JVLC2009-potential.pdf):

[image]

In there we have $f_1^{1/2}(u)$ and $f_2^{1/2}(u)$. Am I supposed to interpret this as the half derivative? Or do they mean the functional square root?

Comment: I'm assuming $f^{1/2}(u) = (f(u))^{1/2}$

Comment: I thought it might be just the Square Root, that's how it's coded at the moment. But one of my engineering friends seemed to think that wasn't correct.